# TypeError: conn.db is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

I get this error when I try to connect to a collection in my mongodb database:
TypeError: conn.db is not a function

PS: I'm using version 4.4.6

Thank you for your help!

```
export default class OfferingDAO {
static async injectDB(conn){
    if(offerings){
        return;
    }
    try { 
        offerings = await conn.db(process.env.NS).collection("Offering");
    }
    catch(e){
        console.error(`Unable to establish a collection handle in OfferingDAO: ${e}`);
    }
}
```

Here is my the code to connect to mongodb:

```
await mongoose.connect(process.env.URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true
})
.then(async (client) => {
  await OfferingDAO.injectDB(client);
  app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
  }) 
})
```

Comment: Can you add the code to the connection constructor? Seems like the conn variable is not set correctly.

Comment: `process.env.URI` is a string already you don't have to wrap it with quotes. And how do you call `conn.db`? I couldn't see the function you export `conn`

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs, the client is your db instance only:

```
// Using `mongoose.connect`...
var promise = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp', {
  useMongoClient: true,
  /* other options */
});
promise.then(function(db) {
  /* Use `db`, for instance `db.model()`
});
```

So your code should work if it is updated to :

```
offerings = await conn.collection("Offering");
```